# Find min distance coordinate in 2D space from list coordinates

Tags: algorithm, coordinates, distance

What is the best and faster way to resolve this problem?

- Have a list of coordinates `x,y => (x1,y1),(x..,y..),(xn,yn)` ;  `x, y > 0` (intergers)
- Find in all 2D space the coordinate (a,b)  with the min sum `manhattan` distance from all point.

`a, b` can be different from `(xn,yn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Find median point A using only X-coordinates.
Find median point B using only Y-coordinates.
Point with components `(A.X, B.Y)` is what you need.

Example for 7 points:

point C is median by X - it goes 4-th in order of X-coordinates
point D is median by Y - it goes 4-th in order of Y-coordinates
min dist coordinate is `(5,3)` (marked by cross)

[image]

Comment: Has or could you palese descrive the alghoritm?

Comment: Look at example.

Comment: Thanks! Buy of the Array is of odd size and we are in int 2D space?

Comment: I've  shown odd size array and 2D space. For even-size array there are two median elements, needed coordinate might be in any place between them